# virtual field in a model part of the model but not in the DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a standard model with a few fields that are saved to a DB, and I need 1 field that doesn't have to be saved.

I tried attr_accessor but that doesn't cover it. Using Attr_accessor I can set and get the field, but it is not part of the model. If I add the models to an array and then see what is in the virtual field is not part of it. I also tried to add the field :headerfield to attr_accessible but that didn't change anything.

How can I get a field that is part of the model but not saved to the database?

The model

```
class Mapping < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :internalfield, :sourcefield
  attr_accessor :headerfield
end
```

console output:

```
1.9.3-p194 :001 > m = Mapping.new
 => #<Mapping id: nil, internalfield: nil, sourcefield: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, data_set_id: nil>
1.9.3-p194 :002 > m.headerfield = "asef"
 => "asef"
1.9.3-p194 :003 > m
 => #<Mapping id: nil, internalfield: nil, sourcefield: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, data_set_id: nil>
```

Comment: It actually _is_ part of the model, only you won't see it outputted using console in the manner you are attempting.  Where do you need this virtual attribute to be used?

Comment: I need it in a pure javascript client, no rails views. Rendering the object to JSON doesn't give me the attribute either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because ActiveRecord::Base has custom implementations for the standard serializiation methods (including `to_s` and `as_json`), you will never see your model attributes that do not have backing database columns unless you intervene in some way.

You can render it to JSON using the following:

```
render json: my_object, methods: [:virtual_attr1, :virtual_attr2]
```

Or you can use the `as_json` serializer directly:

```
my_object.as_json(methods: [:virtual_attr1, :virtual_attr2])
```

Answer (score 0):

The return you see in the console is nothing else but the value of to_s. For this case, code should be better than natural language, take a look in the following code and see if you understand

```
class A
end
 => nil
A.new
 => #<A:0xb73d1528>
A.new.to_s
 => "#<A:0xb73d1528>"

class A
  def to_s
    "foobar"
  end
end
 => nil
A.new
 => ble
A.new.to_s
 => "ble"
```

You can see this output because `ActiveRecord::Base` defines a method `to_s` that take into account only the attributes that are defined in the database, not the attr_accessor methods, maybe using the `attributes` call.

Comment: I understand the example, although I'm wondering where "foobar" is gone and where "ble" is born. But why is to_s working on the attributes that are written to the db and not on the attributes created with attr_accessor?